# PHP works with HTML but not with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to use jquery to call the php to display the data on the same page. However, if i use a jquery to call the data, i keep getting "0 Results" but when i use the submit button, i get the correct data in the .php window...Any help is appreciated! thank you!

oh i have the three scripts in different files but have linked the jquery in the head in html file. Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="contract.php">
 <fieldset>
    <div class="wrap_21">
      <fieldset id="accountnumber">
               <input type="text" name="accountnumber" placeholder="Account Number" value="" required style="width:240px; height:24px"/>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap_16">
              <fieldset id="tradetype">
                   <span class="text_9">TRADE:</span>
                   <span class="text_11">
                   <input type="radio" name="tradetype" required value="Buy"/> Buy
                   <input type="radio" name="tradetype" value="Sell"/> Sell </span>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <span class="text_9">PRICE:</span>
                  <span class="text_11">
                  <input type="text" name="price" value="" required /></span>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <span class="text_9">DATE:</span>
                  <select name="date" id="date" onchange="showData(this.Value)">
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      <option value="24 November 2015">24-Nov-15</option>
                      <option value="24 December 2015">24-Dec-15</option>
                      <option value="24 January 2015">24-Jan-15</option>
                  </select>
              </fieldset>
          <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit">
 </fieldset>
```

PHP

```
    <?php
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);
}

$tradetype=$_POST['tradetype'];
$price=$_POST['price'];
$date=$_POST['date'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE Trade='$tradetype' AND ExpiryDate='$date'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Premium: " . $row["Premium"]. " Discount: " . $row["Discount"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Jquery

```
    function showData(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","contract.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: do you want to submit the form with only JavaScript or both?

Comment: i want the user to fill the form, check if the price is ok for them and then submit to my database.

Answer (score 1):

this is your problem: `showData(this.Value)`,in your php you have 3 post variable you are sending just one

Try something like this:

remove `onchange="showData(this.Value)` from the select

```
$('select[name="date"]').on('change',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var parent = $(this).parents('form');
  $.ajax({url: "contract.php",
   type:"POST",
   data:{
       'tradetype':parent.find('input[name="tradetype"]').val(),
       'price':parent.find('input[name="price"]').val(),
       'date':parent.find('option:selected').val()
   },
  success: function(result) {
    $("#result").html(result);
}});
```

Comment: hello! sry i am not sure how to fix that... very new to php and jquery. Could you please elaborate on how i can solve that?

Comment: hi madalin --> it doesnt work... there is no data displayed :(

Comment: do you think by defining them under parents i need to change in .php file as well?

Comment: no, parent means i select data only from this form and not from other forms present on the page

Answer (score 1):

complete html code:-

```
<form method="get" id="formpge" action="">
 <fieldset>
    <div class="wrap_21">
      <fieldset id="accountnumber">
               <input type="text" name="accountnumber" id="accountnumber" placeholder="Account Number" value="" required style="width:240px; height:24px"/>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap_16">
              <fieldset id="tradetype">
                   <span class="text_9">TRADE:</span>
                   <span class="text_11">
                   <input type="radio" name="tradetype" id="tradetype" required value="Buy"/> Buy
                   <input type="radio" name="tradetype" id="tradetype" value="Sell"/> Sell </span>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <span class="text_9">PRICE:</span>
                  <span class="text_11">
                  <input type="text" name="price" id="price" value="" required /></span>
              </fieldset>
              <fieldset>
                  <span class="text_9">DATE:</span>
                  <select name="date" id="date" >
                      <option value="">Select</option>
                      <option value="24 November 2015">24-Nov-15</option>
                      <option value="24 December 2015">24-Dec-15</option>
                      <option value="24 January 2015">24-Jan-15</option>
                  </select>
              </fieldset>
          <input type="button" name="formSubmit" id="formSubmit" value="Submit">
          <div id="result"></div>
 </fieldset>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ //newly added 

      $( "#date" ).change(function() {

        event.preventDefault();

            var data = $( "#formpge" ).serialize();
            var url = 'contract.php?'+data;
              $.get( , function( data ) {
                $( "#result" ).html( data );

            });

      });
  });
  </script>
```

in your php change $_POST to $_GET;

Comment: In the form he is sending the values as method="post". How can he retrieve the values in the other page with $_GET.?

Comment: @sanjeevshetty in my answer i change the method to get.

Comment: You changed it now. ;)

Comment: yeah but it wont matter because it's submitting via ajax get

Answer (score 0):

you haven't pass

tradetype ,price,date; parameter in  request

so try like

```
function showData(str) {
   var data={
       tradetype :$('#tradetype').val(),
       price:$('#price').val(),
       date:$('#date').val()
  };
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST","contract.php",true);
  xmlhttp.send(data);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about XmlHttpRequest, I haven't used it much. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) .open doesn't take a data parameter, but .send does...

Comment: does not work... same issue keep getting the 0 result and not the PHP real result

Comment: please correct your query like $sql = "SELECT * FROM Contracts WHERE Trade=".$tradetype." AND ExpiryDate=".$date;

Answer (score -1):

You can get a detailed tutorial here -

http://www.a100websolutions.in/retrieve-data-using-jquery-php/

Full tutorial with a demo on how to get data from database using AJAX / JQuery and PHP at the backend. Also, the codes are in there so you can refer to the codes as well.